# how do i connect a uitableview to a uitableviewcontroller programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

So i have a:

```
arrangeList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(attributesPadding, y, popoverWidth - 2* attributesPadding, popoverHeight - y - attributesPadding) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

That is the tableview that i want to connect to a controller, and i also have added this tableview to a uiview that i have animate onto the screen in based on a click. So i subclassed uiviewcontroller and created this :

```
arrangeListViewController = [[[ArrangeListViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Now how do i make it so that the 'arrangeList' is populated based on 'arrangeListViewController'?

Is this approach way wrong ? any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to look at something like:

```
arrangeListViewController.tableView = arrangeList;
[arrangeList release]; //avoid leaking the arrangeList
```

Personally, I prefer setting this up in InterfaceBuilder, but it'll work programatically as well.

Hope this helps.  Andrew.

Comment: Thank you good sir. Unfortunately IB wont let me do some of the things i would like.

Comment: So hey, now when i click something in my list, it isnt triggering my - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

method, do i need to set the delegate somehow too?

Comment: interesting.  the table fills with data, but the row selection isn't triggered?  I would expect that if the cells are being populated then that proves the table view is correctly wired up.  I might need to see some code.